# hello, i can't figure out why the below this is pointing to the global object , i thought it would point to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

i can't figure out why  this keyword in the below code is pointing to the global object ,since I'm using an arrow function in .then . i thought it would point to the user  object:

the below function is in my User Controller:

```
   exports.register = function(req, res) {
      let user = new User(req.body)
      user.register().then(()=> {
        //this is pointing to global object not user object
        console.log(this)
        req.session.user ={username: user.data.username}
        req.session.save(()=>res.redirect('/'))
      })
      .catch((regErrors)=>{
        console.log(regErrors)
         regErrors.forEach((e)=>{
            req.flash('regErrors',e)
          })
          req.session.save(()=>res.redirect('/'))
      })
    }
```

register method code :

```
User.prototype.register = function(){
  return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) =>{
    //  Validate user data
    this.cleanUp()
    await this.validate()
    // save the user data into a database if errors array is empty 
    if (!this.errors.length) {
      // hash user password
      let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
      this.data.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.data.password, salt)
      usersCollection.insertOne(this.data)
      resolve()

    }
    else {
      reject(this.errors)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Why do you think it should point to `user`?

Comment: `this` often isn't what you expect in javascript. If it isn't well defined, don't assume it would even be the same across browsers.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey — `this` is *very* well defined

Comment: @Quentin well that depends on the usage, what library it is called from and how well it was documented. we certainly don't have the information from this question on what `this` would be here. May not even be a real promise object.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey - if the .then callback were a *regular* function then you may have a point (also assuming we are not dealing with a "real Promise"), however, it is an arrow function, so ...

Comment: @xehpuk..since I'm using an arrow function in .then

Comment: There is no indication why `this` would be a user object. If you use an arrow function in `.then` that means `this` would depend on the context of `function (req, res) {}`, which is not related to the user object at all.